# Admin route group with prefix, middleware and named routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-6

I have some named routes in a controller named `VehicleController`:

```
vehicle.index
vehicle.show
```

And then I have an admin section, where I have defined a route group with prefix and middleware. In this section I have a resource controller name  `AdminVehicleController` to handle CRUD tasks for the `Vehicle` (not sure if this is best practice) with the following routes:

```
vehicle.index
vehicle.create
vehicle.store
...
```

However these named routes are conflicting. My routes `web.php` looks like this for now:

```php
Route::get('vehicles', 'VehicleController@index')->name('vehicle.index');
Route::get('vehicle/{vehicle}', 'VehicleController@show')->name('vehicle.show');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'is.admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'AdminDashboardController@index');
    Route::resource('vehicle', 'AdminVehicleController');
});
```

If I add `'name' => 'admin'` to the `Route::group()` array, the route names will be `adminvehicle.index` and not `admin.vehicle.index`.

What is the correct way to combine all these parameters in the route?

Comment: you can use `as` key, `'as'=> 'admin.'`, notice the `.` at end of `admin`. [ref](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes)

Comment: I tried that, but for the `admin` (dashboard URL) the named route will be `admin.` - Not a huge problem, but annoying.

Comment: you can also name it as `dashboard` so it will be `admin.dashboard`, so that will be much cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `as` parameter for your admin group

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'is.admin', 'as'=> 'admin.'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'AdminDashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
    Route::resource('vehicle', 'AdminVehicleController');
});
```

Reference [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes)

Answer (score 1):

Supply a `names` array as part of the third parameter `$options` array, with each key being the resource controller method (index, store, edit, etc.), and the value being the name you want to give the route.

```
    Route::resource('vehicle', 'AdminVehicleController', [
        'names' => [
            'index' => 'admin.vehicle.index',
            // etc...
        ]
    ]);
```